# conditional expression in TeX

Tags: conditionals

User case:
This is what I have in mind. I am preparing a contract written in tex. I would like to specify in the beginning of the contract whether this will be an open contract. if so, I want text to add section{ABC}, if not, then section ABC is not executated.

I know there are similar questions asked, but to be honest, it is too confusing and I still don't know how to proceed after doing my research. I assume I should use \if primitive?

Some pseydocode I have in mind

```
\newcommand{\opencontract}{TRUE}

...
\if \opencontract=TRUE
\section{ABC}
***
\fi
...
```

Comment: Other possibility: see “Boolean Flags” in the [etoolbox manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\newif\ifopencontract
```

in your preamble then

```
\opencontracttrue
```

or

```
\opencontractfalse
```

then

```
\ifopencontract
  whatever
 \else
   foobar
\fi
```

in conditional sections